# How does Process Lasso trim an applications memory?

Tags: memory, ssd, process

In Lasso trim, there is an option to trim an applications memory. The "Trim Memory" function in Process Lasso is designed to reclaim and release system memory.

In a personal project of mine, I am currently trying to replicate this functionality. One way I have tried doing is by utilizing the EmptyWorkingSet function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-emptyworkingset).
I have also tried using the SetProcessWorkingSetSize function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-setprocessworkingsetsize). All the attempts result in no difference to the memory.

If anyone could provide some useful insights into how this function works inside of process lasso, It would be much appreciated